# Why does 'import dataclasses' cause logging to stop working?

Tags: python, logging, import, python-dataclasses

I have the follow bit of code:

```py
import logging
# import dataclasses

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="logfile.log",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)

def main():
    logging.info("This is an info message")
    logging.error("This is an error message")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I comment out `import dataclasses` the logs are outputted properly. But if I include `import dataclasses` it stops outputting completely.

**Does anyone know why this is? Perhaps a bug?**

Python version: 3.9.16

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.9.13. I suspect you've named a file something that shadows a standard library module (like `dataclasses.py`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what seems to be causing my issue. I have the following simplified project layout:

```
project/
  script_one/
    script_one.py
  script_two/
    script_two.py
```

script_one.py:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="script_one.log",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)

def main() -> None:
    logging.info("Starting script...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

script_two.py:

```py
import logging
import dataclasses

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="logfile.log",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)

def main():
    logging.info("This is an info message")
    logging.error("This is an error message")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that `script_one.py` also contains `logging.basicConfig` outside of the main function. Apparently this caused the logs in `script_two.py` to be output to `script_one.log`, despite only running `script_two.py` (these scripts don't import each other).

**I am curious why Python works this way...
And also why `import dataclasses` triggers this issue...**

Anyway, the solution is to just use a separate logger function and initialize from main:

script_one.py:

```py
import logging

def logger():
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="script_one.log",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
    )

def main() -> None:
    logger()
    logging.info("Starting script...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

script_two.py:

```py
import logging
import dataclasses

def logger():
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="logfile.log",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
    )

def main():
    logger()
    logging.info("This is an info message")
    logging.error("This is an error message")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

----------------------EDIT----------------------

I now fully understand what was happening after placing `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` in `script_one.py` as suggested by @user2357112:

```
File "/home/user/project/script_two/script_two.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dataclasses import dataclass
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/dataclasses.py", line 3, in <module>
    import copy
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/user/project/copy/copy.py", line 8, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
```

As it so happens, my `script_one.py` that I used in the example was actually called `copy.py`. Since `dataclasses` imports the `copy` module, it instead imports my `copy.py` which then runs the logging statement, outputting to the other file.

Mystery solved!

Comment: Does one of these scripts happen to be named `dataclasses.py`, or anything else that would clash with a standard library module?

Comment: Nope, nothing named `dataclasses.py` in any of my scripts. It's just imported in `script_two.py` in this example.

Comment: Put `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` in `script_one.py`, and you should get a better understanding of what's going on to cause it to be imported.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112, this made it clear. Explanation added to my answer!

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` is meant to be called *once* per script. It's not clear how your two scripts are related (or how `script_one` manages to call it twice, but it's your responsibility to ensure that `basicConfig` is only called once. Make sure you are making a clear distinction between scripts and modules in your application, and ensure that no *module* ever calls `logging.basicConfig`. Usually, you call it from inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.